# Chart Div 100% height of window

Tags: html, css

So i have a chartist.js chart, that I wan't to fill the whole page hight. The thing is, that it should just fill the height, relative to the parent container. So if I add a sibling div to the chart div, it should still not overflow the window size.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dckuLxyf/

Heres my html and javascript:

```
<div class="container fill">
  <div><h1>My Chart</h1></div>
  <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth my-chart"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var data = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
    series: [
      [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
    ]
  };

  new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
</script>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:pink;
}

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.my-chart {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

If I remove the h1 div I get the behaviour I want, but I would also like to have the H1 on top of it, and still behave the same way (not overflowing below the screen) How do i accomplish this? I have tried changing the positioning of each div, but without any luck. I think i'm missing the detail in how positioning works in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex to help hold everything together : https://jsfiddle.net/dckuLxyf/4/

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:pink;
}

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

.my-chart {
  flex:1 1 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: And we are golden! :) Thank you sir!